# Multiple table in one dataSheet

Tags: jquery, excel, datatable, datatables

Can we have more than one table in one datasheet so that the filters applied like (from Date, to Date, type etc) on data could come along, We want to have the filter data along in the downloaded excel file.

Same can be reached using ClosedXml.dll in C#

Reference image :

[image]

Comment: You can have more than 1 table on a sheet. You would need to use a macro to filter the second table and it may be simpler to use the filter dropdown built in to Excel.

Comment: @Gordon Requirement is to achieve the same in jquery datatable, is there any way ?